# Swap year and day in a Date in Access using SQL

Tags: sql, csv, date, ms-access

I need to import data into an access database from a csv file. The issue that I'm having is that access will mess up the date.

The date format in the csv file is among the lines of "29-SEP-17". When this is imported to access, it translates it as 2029/09/17 - basically mixing up the day and year parts of the date.

I can resolve this by going to excel before importing and changing the date fields in the file to short date, but I would prefer to modify this AFTER importing into access using an SQL query for all date fields in the table. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the rest of the answers provided are for SQL Server and not MS Access.  Your best bet is to write your own date parse function to have the most control and utilize it in whatever way makes the most sense (if your parsing the csv using VBA, update query, etc.)

This can be used in MS Access Queries as well.  Here is an update example of an in place date format update:

```
UPDATE [MyTable] SET [MyTable].[MyDateToConv] = MyDateParse([MyTable].[MyDateToConv])
```

```vb
Public Sub TestParse()

    Debug.Print MyDateParse("29-SEP-17") '9/29/2017

End Sub

Public Function MyDateParse(val As Variant) As Variant

    Dim dPart As Variant
    Dim mVal As Long

    If IsNull(val) Then
        MyDateParse = Null
        Exit Function
    End If

    dPart = Split(val, "-")

    If UBound(dPart) <> 2 Then
        'value isn't of format ##-XXX-## handle how you please
    End If

    Select Case Trim(UCase(dPart(1))) 'select case based on the month
        Case "JAN"
            mVal = 1
        Case "FEB"
            mVal = 2
        Case "MAR"
            mVal = 3
        Case "APR"
            mVal = 4
        Case "MAY"
            mVal = 5
        Case "JUN"
            mVal = 6
        Case "JUL"
            mVal = 7
        Case "AUG"
            mVal = 8
        Case "SEP"
            mVal = 9
        Case "OCT"
            mVal = 10
        Case "NOV"
            mVal = 11
        Case "DEC"
            mVal = 12
        Case Else
            'however you want to handle this error
    End Select

    MyDateParse = DateSerial(dPart(2), mVal, dPart(0))
End Function
```

Comment: Let OP know he/she can call this user-defined method inside an MS Access query.

Answer (score 0):

> From 29-SEP-17

```
SELECT TO_DATE( (SUBSTR('29-SEP-17',1,7) || '20' || SUBSTR('29-SEP-17',8,2)) 
,'dd-MON-yyyy') FROM DUAL;
```

> will add the '20' in front of '17' to make '2017', after that will convert the string to DATE type.
>
> 2017-09-29 00:00:00 (or however the default date format of your system is).
>   Or you can also use CONCAT like so:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( CONCAT (SUBSTR(yourDate,1,7), '20', SUBSTR(yourDate,8,2)) ) 
        FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Can I replace the '29-SEP-17' with the date field name and replace "DUAL" with my table name? I'm also getting an error popping up: Invalid use of vertical bars in query expression...

Comment: @asj Yes you can. DUAL was just used as an example. I updated the answer anyways and replace || with CONCAT. Although it should work both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *import wizard* to import your data.

In this, click *Advanced* and specify the *date sequence* to **DMY**, and change the data type for the field from *Short Text* to *Date/Time*.

Now you can import your data right away.